# history of version / price changes for itunes apps

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I'm looking to get "app activity" type information from pages like these. http://appshopper.com/social-networking/tweetee

only that I want to be able to get such information via **"Appid"** that apple used for each app on the appstore. anyone have any ideas on how I might do that?

Comment: I don't understand your reference to "Appid". Are you able to clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 5):

[AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/) does this.  I don't know the answer but you could ask them if there's a way!

Comment: +1 Their search results for app ids (the number between `…/id` and `?mt=…` in iTunes URLs) for a few iOS and Mac apps all seem to bring up their link for the app in question. The price and update history is in the “App Activity” sidebar on the right.